# Glitchy window controls on new installation

Tags: unity, 16.10

A brand new 16.10 installation with a NVIDIA GTX 1070 -- after one reboot, controls on non-maximsed windows look like this -- there are three circles, but their content appears to be random RBG pixels.

[image]

they should look like this:

[image]

How do I remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to fix this by running `compiz --replace` and `unity --replace`